# Why doesn't this program run faster when using multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
start = time.time()
for i in range (260):
        if i==259:
            print ("a done\n")
            break
for o in range (260):
        if o==259:
            print ("b done\n")
            break 
end = time.time() 
print (end-start)
```

This code is taking time almost " 0.007 " and its reading first the (I) loop then when it finish it start reading the (O) loop

My problem is this code:

```
start = time.time()
def a():
    for i in range (260):
        if i==259:
            print (" a done \n")
            break
def b():
    for o in range (260):
        if o==259:
            print (" b done \n")
            break
th1=Thread(target=a)
th2=Thread(target=b)
th1.start()
th2.start()
th1.join()
th2.join()
end = time.time() 
print (end-start)
```

Even that this code is reading the (I) loop and the (O) loop in the same time both of them but its still taking almost "0.008"

And I am thinking that the second code should take half of the time of the first code, but I don't understand why its taking almost the same time as the first code?

Comment: CPython uses a global interpreter lock (GIL) that only lets one thread run at a time. This lets its memory manager run faster at the expense of full multithreading. In your case, only one of the threads could run at a time.

Comment: Just to give you some vocabulary for future reference, what you've discovered here is that Python threads give you *concurrency* but not *parallelism*.

Comment: Also you should consider that even if there were no Global Interpreter lock the overhead of the thread creation, scheduling and tear down would add overhead. This would be noticeable for such a short running program and wouldn't offer a 2x speedup.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the [global interpreter lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). I/O and C extensions are outside of the GIL, but threads of pure Python work do not actually work in parallel.

If you do want to perform Python code in parallel, see [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). It has an API similar to threading (as well as new functionality too).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p1 = Process(target=a)
p2 = Process(target=b)
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: for some reason i cant use the multiprocessing  module i dont know why you can see my other question asking why the multiprocessing not working for me and no one answered me yet

Comment: so do you have any other modules i could try ?

Comment: @ مهندعبدالجليل isn't your other question answered? You never joined the process, so it hasn't completed by the time your main program exits.

Comment: @مهندعبدالجليل Are you sure you don't need `if __name__ == "__main__"`? Are you on windows?

Comment: yes i tried to join too but didnt work too i am using python 3.5.2

Comment: @مهند عبد الجليل: If you have the `subprocess` module you can create separate processes.

Comment: yes i am on windows and i used this if __name__ == "__main__" and it also still the same problem i could record my screen if you want to i am making game now and i really really need to use the multiprocessing  :(

Comment: ok i will search about the subprocess thank you for your help i am really thankful